# Is this statement grammatically correct? [Thank you so much for your time and efforts; I really appreciate it]

Tags: grammar, semicolons, grammaticality

**Is this statement grammatically correct regarding the usage of the semicolon, it makes sense, etc? I sometimes put this at the end of an email.**

*Thank you so much for your time and efforts; I really appreciate it.*

.

P.S: I'm not an ESL language learner. This is just a grammar question I had.

Comment: So you're not concerned about the use of "it" with reference to time and efforts. You're just wondering about the semi-colon?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it's correct. The semicolon is used to join two independent clauses whose meanings are very closely related and when you haven't already used a conjunction. The use of a semicolon is generally employed when the author wishes to communicate an extended pause (one that is lengthier than a standard comma) but doesn't wish to introduce a full stop and split the phrase into two distinct sentences altogether.